# Integral of a parametrized commutator

Tags: matrices, finite-groups, integration

I am trying to solve the following integral
$$
\int_{-1}^{1}\;db\;||[t_{b}(A),J]||_{F}^{2}
$$
where $t_{b}$ is the entrywise threshold of the matrix A ($0$ if $a_{ij}<b$, $a_{ij}$ if $a_{ij}>b$, with $|a_{i,j}|\in [0,1]$ ). Further $A$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix, $J$ is the all ones matrix and $F$ indicates the Frobenius norm (the zero or one norm will work as well).

Any hope?

Thanks a lot!

Fabio

Note: an equivalent problem would be if $t_{b}(A)$  is the hadamard $p$-power of $A$ and we substitute the integral with the sum $\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}$. I also tried to solve the integral in this last formulation but without success.

Comment: I am curious to know why this has a "finite groups" tag?

Comment: Could you rewrite the equivalent problem formally. Is it of the form $\sum_{p \ge 1} \|[A^{\circ p}-J]\|^2$?

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Hi Geoff, the matrix A should be coming from  a multiplication table of a group.

Comment: @Survit Hi Survit, I can rewrite it as $\sum_{p=1}^{\infty} ||A^{\circ p}J- JA^{\circ p} ||_{F}^{2}$. Thanks.